# jQuery - Selecting li before button

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I got a list like:

```
    <li>
        <a data-id="..." data-name="..." data-vname="..." style="font-weight: 400; padding: 5px 15px; cursor: pointer;">
            <span class="badge badge-primary pull-right"><?php echo $count;?></span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-server push-5-r"></i> ...
        </a>
    </li>
```

Now I want to do a click function for the `<a>` Element, which gives the li the class active and when I click another object to remove it from the first. My first try:

```
$( "a" ).click(function() {
        $( this ).prev().addClass('active');
});
```

How to select the `<li>` before this() ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Key fact: The `li` isn't *before* the button, it *contains* the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can even do

```
$( "a" ).click(function() {
      $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

to remove it from all the other `li` and add it to current `a`'s `li` you can just write one more line

```
$( "a" ).click(function() {
      $('li').removeClass('active')//removes it from all the li
      $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');//adds it to current anchor's li
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks alot.

Comment: Anytime.. happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 4):

The [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev) method is used to fetch the previous sibling element, where as in your case the `li` is an ancestor element.

To get the direct parent(as in your case) you can use [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent), but if you are after a parent in some levels up you can use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest)

```
$( "a" ).click(function() {
        $( this ).parent().addClass('active');
        //or $( this ).closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks alot.